# how to retrieve the image path from database and display it in html using jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

This is my jsp code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usha","root","mysql");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
               String query="select name from image";

            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next())
            {
                %><img src="<%=rs.getString("name")%>"/><%
            }

            st.close();

            con.close();
```

Comment: Why you are adding `localhost` in source path. ?

Comment: i removed that,but i cant get the image

Comment: Is the image location same as the jsp page? Or different? If different then you need to resolve it with relative path. Example: `<img src="images/<%=rs.getString("name")%>"/>`

Comment: now,am got it.. thank u...